# Is there a documented way to reset the lambda parameter on an existing std::exponential_distribution object?

Tags: c++, c++11, exponential-distribution

When I look at the documentation for [std::exponential_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/exponential_distribution), it does not seem to expose a standard way for changing the lambda parameter at runtime.

There is a `param` method, but it takes the opaque member type `param_type`, and the only documented way of obtaining an object of this type is to call `param` with no arguments, but that would imply a different instance must have first been created with that parameter.

Below, I show two non-documented ways of resetting lambda that compile, but I do not know whether they will result in correct behavior at runtime.

```
#include <random>
#include <new>

int main(){
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::exponential_distribution<double> intervalGenerator(5);

    // How do we change lambda after creation?
    // Construct a param_type using an undocumented constructor?
    intervalGenerator.param(std::exponential_distribution<double>::param_type(7));

    // Destroy and recreate the distribution?
    intervalGenerator.~exponential_distribution();
    new (&intervalGenerator) std::exponential_distribution<double>(9);
}
```

**Is there a documented way to do this, and if not, are either of the two solutions safe to use?**

Comment: It's not undocumented. `param_type` can always be constructed using the same parameters as the parent distribution.

Comment: @Praetorian, Is there documentation on its constructor? I could not find any.

Comment: The fact that `param_type` can be constructed using the same parameters as its distribution is one of the requirements of the `RandomNumberDistribution` concept (26.5.1.6/9).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just assign a new generator to the old instance:

```
std::exponential_distribution<double> intervalGenerator(5);
intervalGenerator = std::exponential_distribution<double>(7);
```

Portable, easy to read and obviously correct.

---

Also,

```
intervalGenerator.param(std::exponential_distribution<double>::param_type(7));
```

is safe as described in 26.5.1.6/9 in both N3337 and N4141, so you can use that too. But with the first variant, no portability questions arise to begin with.

Comment: I'm trying to minimize overheads for this change, and I'm concerned about paying for an additional object. It seems silly one must throw away the object and create a whole new object just to reset a parameter.

Comment: @merlin2011 There will be no overhead. Stop wasting your time guessing about performance, optimize after actually finding a problem.

Comment: @Fanael, Fair point. Perhaps I overthought this. :P Will accept when timer expires.

Comment: @Fanael Also works even at `-O1`. It's an easy optimization for the compiler

Comment: @Justin: works even at `-Og`. I just use `-O3` as the default.

Comment: On Clang, it seems to need `-O2`, though